# Xcode 9 Navigation bar issue after navigating from Left Side Menu on iOS 11 not on iOS 10.3 and below

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode9

After updating from Xcode 8 to Xcode 9 I've noticed this very strange behaviour in the navigation bar only on devices running iOS 11.

This bug appears after navigating from my left side menu that show the menu controller you choose modally with a default presentation (That is Full Screen)

I've posted a video here: https://youtu.be/mgjlbkMi-N8

It seems a bug of the compilation on Xcode 9.

Tryed also on real device iPad Pro with iOS 11. 
The same code compiled with Xcode 8.3.3 works as expected, while compiled with Xcode 9 exposes the issue.

I've put a playground code here: https://github.com/shadowsheep1/xcode9navigationissue

With already a workaround: set the presentation to Over Full Screen.

But that has no meaning this is not the exptected operation.

Once the navigation bar is broken, is broken for every navigation controller in the App.

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

> **Apple Developer Relations January 23 2018, 11:13 PM**
>
> There are no plans
>   to address this based on the following:
>
> You are creating a detached presentation, which is causing multiple
>   navigation bars to be placed in the view hierarchy. The navigation bar
>   that is seen is not the one where pushes are happening, thus the error
>   in display. I don’t know why this didn’t happen on iOS 10, but it was
>   an invalid configuration there as well.
>
> We would recommend that you use a proper view controller container to
>   implement this menu, rather than what seems to be done (the
>   IS_SlideMenu_View being placed directly in the window).

Comment: Any modal presentation with navigation controller in it has the same problem

Comment: @akaDuality I've posted the bug here https://bugreport.apple.com and up to now still compiling with Xcode 8.3.3

Comment: @akaDuality Do you present modally your views programmatically or by segue from Interface Builder?

Comment: programmatically

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with regular `UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical`.

I've solved it by setting `UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen` or `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext`.

Possibly it also helps you.

Example for navigation that is presented modally:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
   navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
}
```

Comment: That's the workaround I've suggested in the question, but what I cannot understand is whether this is the right choice because Apple changed this behaviour or if this is a real bug when presenting modally views with default presentation programmatically. I guess this last scenario. Anyway if you set OverFullScreen you have a different UI look and feel because the underline view it's not destroyed.

Comment: Ooops, I hadn't see it during reading. You're right, the behaviour is very frustrating